# Why does it seem like my for loop is not returning the correct index?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

```js
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {

  var index;
  var sortedArr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i++) {
    if (sortedArr[i] > num) {
      index = sortedArr.indexOf(sortedArr[i]);
    }
  }
  return index;
}

console.log(getIndexToIns([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 35)); //returns 4?
console.log(getIndexToIns([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 30)); //also returns 4?
```

To me, it should return index 3, not 4, as the number in index 4 is 50, and my num variable is 35, which is smaller than 40(at  index 3). Is my logic wrong? I can't seem to figure out why.

In the second one, it is also returning index 4, when  the index should be index 2?

Comment: Uh, wouldn't you expect `sortedArr.indexOf(sortedArr[i])` to just be `i`?

Comment: @user202729 I have not, to be honest I am actually not quiet sure how to do that yet

Comment: Well you are `return`ing your `index` **after** the (whole) loop. What value would you expect it to have there?

Comment: You continue in the loop after hitting the first value > num. So you will always go to the end and return sortedArr.length - 1.

Comment: @Jesse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code

Comment: Too much wrong here to correct.  Suggestion: drop the tutorial you're following and pick up a book

Comment: @vol7ron: Don't be so dramatic; it can be fixed with one statement.

Comment: What you _should_ do, OP, is run through your program on paper with a pencil and check the value of everything at each step. That is, debug it.

Comment: @vol7ron what else did I screw up?  I have no been programming long at all

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's not counting the unnecessary inefficiency (`1` the array is modified `2` why don't the OP just binary search `3` it doesn't need to be sorted, just need to count how many elements are less than the value, which is `O(n)`)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit got it, will do that next time

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's not about fixing it, it's about learning the proper conventions.  Any meaningful answer should address the shortcomings and inadequacies and (for me) that'd take either too much effort or time (especially on a mobile device).  It's not the worse code, just too many ways to improve that a book should solve.

Comment: @Jesse If you have a working code and you want to know where is it not-the-best-practice, you can post on [codereview.se]. I'm not very familiar with that site so read their help center before asking.

Comment: @vol7ron: You claimed _"too much wrong here to correct"_ which is proven false by the two correct answers.

Comment: @vol7ron If you add them to a snippet, consider `console.log` them.

Comment: @user202729 oh alright, thanks for the suggestion first time I am hearing of that site. I'll try that next

Comment: (remember to read their Help center and How to ask before asking, if you ask poor questions there people will blame me, I've experienced some users asking bad questions on [PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com) and was misinformed by another SE user, of course I was annoyed)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit questioning if you see everything wrong.  Again, it's not about writing a concise correct code.. that can be done in one line.  It's about advising on what's wrong.  If you don't see that, then let's agree to disagree :)

Comment: @user202729 if you would like to do that, you are welcome to.  The purpose of the edit was not to correct grammar, code, or anything else.  It was strictly to move from a code to a snippet for anyone that wanted to copy to answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49441599/183181) for a number of issues that wouldn't be right to not address in an answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to break out of your loop:

```
for (var i=0 ; i< sortedArr.length; i++){
  if (sortedArr[i] > num){
    index = sortedArr.indexOf(sortedArr[i]);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, ok is that because the loop is still going even after it finds a value grater than num?  so I need to break the loop once it find that value so it does not continue to go through the whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

Your loop will run even after it finds the first valid index. You can return index inside the loop to break, or call break yourself, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A functional alternative to consider :)

This will return the index of the first element in the array `arr` that is strictly larger than the number `num`:

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
    return arr.findIndex(e => e > num);
}
```

Comment: Watch your [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're right. Just crush my dreams of beautiful code :(

Comment: Heh, sorry... :P

Answer (score 0):

### Issue Correction

Here's a few of your issues:

1. `var index;` 
    the variable is unnecessary since this is a simple function and you can return from the for-block.  That's not completely bad practice as it's good to return a variable in more complicated functions
2. `var sortedArr`
    start using `let` and using a transpiler/packer if needed
3. `arr.sort(function(a, b) {` 
    shorten with arrow functions (again transpiler/packer is your friend)
4. `for (var i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i++) {` 
    cache your `.length` into a variable for a minor performance bump

   - Example: `for(var i=0,n=sortedArr.length; i<n; i++)`
5. `if (sortedArr[i] > num) {
         index = sortedArr.indexOf(sortedArr[i]);
       }
     }`

   1. because you're not returning `index` from within the loop, the index would be overwritten with every subsequent *true* condition.  In this case, the first true pass would be `40` and index would be set to `3`, but then the loop would iterate again and come across `50`, which is also bigger than your `num`, so `index` would be set to 4 and eventually to be returned
   2. so many unnecessary curly braces
   3. You have an inherit issue that you are returning the index of your **sorted array** and not your passed-in array.  This means, that the index that's returned no longer corresponds with the argument.

      Maybe you didn't notice this because the argument you've passed in appears to already be sorted, but this could be a major silent error if your array was not pre-sorted and you were looking for the index within it.

      *A better way to write it:*

      ```
      if( sortedArr[i] > num )
          return arr.indexOf( sortedArr[i] )
      ```

---

The following includes some quick helper functions (e.g., `log`) for formatting the log output.  It is unnecessary, but a quick way to visually scan if you received the correct output for what you expected.  Additionally a generic (basic) *numeric* sort function was added to make the code more readable. I find that function completely basic, but in your code you were re-defining the function with each call to your `getIndexToIns`, which is an unnecessary performance penalty.

---

### Better Browsers

```js
const getIndexToIns = (arr, num) => arr.indexOf(arr.sort(numeric).find(v => v > num))

log('getIndexToIns([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 40)', 4)
log('getIndexToIns([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 35)', 3)
log('getIndexToIns([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 30)', 3)

function numeric(a, b) {
  return a - b
}

function log(s, ex) {
  console.log(`${s} = ${Function('return ' + s)()}`, `     // expected: ${ex}`)
}
```

---

### Internet Explorer

```js
log('getIndexToInsIE([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 40)', 4)
log('getIndexToInsIE([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 35)', 3)
log('getIndexToInsIE([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 30)', 3)

function getIndexToInsIE(arr, num) {
  return (
    arr.indexOf(arr.sort(numeric).filter(function(v) {
      return v > num
    }).shift())
  )
}

function numeric(a, b) {
  return a - b
}

function log(s, ex) {
  console.log(`${s} = ${Function('return ' + s)()}`, `    // expected: ${ex}`)
}
```